# USB SuperDrive Issue

Tags: optical-drive

How can I get the USB Super Drive model A1379 to work with my Mac Pro Quad Core computer?  I rebooted my computer, searched for drives - could not locate it on the Apple computer.  Apple support stated bad drive.  I exchanged the drive and started over with reboot.  This operation did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Apple USB SuperDrive will not work with a Mac Pro. Check the System Requirements [here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD564ZM/A/apple-usb-superdrive).

There are hacks you can try - but it may be better in this case to get a different (3rd party) drive.